# Does "versus" also mean "including"?

Tags: meaning

> Write down during the interview as the person is speaking versus at
>   the end of the interview

In the example above, what does "versus" mean? Does it mean "write down not only during the person is speaking, but also after the end of the interview"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Versus means:

> as opposed to; in contrast to.

So in your sentence it means to write down when the person is speaking **instead of** at the end of the interview. Not both.

Comment: No. I feel this would mean **and**, as the OP said. Please explain your answer

Comment: according to google and as I know as well it means as opposed to

Comment: Yes, but in this context, it means you are to give a side-by-side breakdown, like when you see a edited question.

Comment: @KhushrajRathod I'm not going to reply anymore; i do not understand what you are saying